# unixodbc on ubuntu and libtdsS.so missing

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I've got some issue using freetds on Ubuntu 16.04.
I'm trying to connect to a ms sql server instance with two ubuntu servers.
On one of them no problem I can send requests, everything's fine following this tuto 
https://help.interfaceware.com/kb/904
On the other one I can't seem to get the libtdsS.so file installing unixodbc.
I've installed, deleted and re-install impossible to find the file.
I can't figure out where did I've gone wrong.
Help please
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of it. I've tried with a setup - Alpine, PHP, `pdo_odbc` & MSSQL Sever (in a local network) without the "mysterious" file and it works at least with `SELECT`s though.

In my `odbcinst.ini`, I just omitted the `Setup=xxx` line.

Judging by [this thread](https://freetds.ibiblio.narkive.com/eXnuKKsK/building-libtdss-so-on-mac-os-x), `libtdsS.so` might not be needed:

> I don't know what's this mysterious libtdsS but I noted in many guide
> on internet this file. I think somebody years ago wrote a
> configuration library for unixODBC called libtdsS. But we (I don't
> remember the original author) wrote directly in FreeTDS the
> configuration part so libtdsodbc is file for Setup entry too.